# Python/Excel: Read "%" from python and solve the "else" statement code

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

```
import xlwt
a = 1

if a == 2:
    print("Good")
else:
    time=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    amounts=[-10,45.21,12,-99.1231,83] 
    percentage = 5.0

    wb2 = xlwt.Workbook()
    sh2 = wb2.add_sheet("Sheet1")

    sh2.write(0, 0, "percentage")
    #sh2.write(0, 1, percentage, "%")   #

    i = 0
    for n in time:
        i = i+1
        sh2.write(i, 0, n)

    i = 0
    for n in amounts:
        i = i+1
        sh2.write(i, 1, n)

    wb2.save("time_amts.xls")
```

I want this code to do two things:
1) Write that "%" sign I have in the code to excel
The following error is when I don't have "if" statement, which still applies when I do have the "if" statement

Error:  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'font'`

2) "else" statement prevents writing and creating the excel file

Comment: What do you mean by writing and creating the excel file, do you get a specific error message?

Comment: I don't get any output. No errors either. The excel file doesn't get created.

Answer (score 0):

According to the xlwt docs ([located at readthedocs.org](http://xlwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#xlwt.Worksheet.Worksheet.write)), the fourth argument that `write` takes is a format called style.

If the header of your column shows that it is a percent based number, do you really need to have a % symbol in every single row?

As for your second error, I'm not sure if much can be done about that. You have file permissions to save files right, and your script works fine with the excel file closed?

edit: If you want cell (0,1) to contain `5.0%`, try changing percentage to

```
percentage = "5.0\%"
```

If you're only writing it the one time you can take the easy way out and just do it like that, then have

```
sh.write(0,1,percentage)
```

Comment: Everything works fine. The % sign only needs to be printed in only one cell. I don't need it, but is there a way to get it ? because it would look nice to have it in the excel file. Don't worry about overwriting point. That is okay.

Comment: So you want  cell (0,1) to contain `5.0%`, correct?

Comment: Yes that is what i exactly want

Comment: @Bob H., I've gone ahead and edited my answer to include that. Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: I got a new problem. Will you please look at that?

Comment: I updated the code. I am not gonna worry about the percentage